# jQuery expanding panels delay issue

Tags: jquery, css

The following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fc7D/918/) works fine:

```
$(".expandable span").on('click', function(){

    var open = 'expandable-open',   
        iconAdd = 'icon-add',
        iconRemove = 'icon-subtract';

    if($(this).hasClass(iconAdd)){
        $(".static-hostels-list").removeClass(open);
        $(".expandable span").removeClass(iconRemove).addClass(iconAdd);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass(iconAdd).toggleClass(iconRemove);
    $(this).parent().find(".static-hostels-list").toggleClass(open);

});
```

however when I open one panel and close the other there is a delay between the 2 actions (opening one and closing the other).

I would like to close that gap and make it happening at the same time.

CSS

```
.static-hostels-list {
    list-style-type: inherit;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -o-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
    -o-transition: max-height 1s;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}

.expandable .expandable-open {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle/codepen ?

Comment: Perhaps you should transition-delay property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp ?

Comment: Your js doesn't seem to work, and revise your html. the structure [ul > div > li] seems strange to me.